# replacement without any imports or built in functions?

Tags: python

This is a homework question. I'm defining a function that takes a word and replaces a given char by another char. For example replace("cake","a","o") should return "coke" I have tried

```
def replace(word,char1,char2):
    newString = ""
    for char1 in word:
        char1 = char2
        newString+=char1
    return newString  #returns 'oooo'
```

and

```
def replace(word,char1,char2):
    newString = ""
    if word[char1]:
        char1 = char2
        newString+=char1
    return newString  #TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

I'm assuming my first attempt is closer to what I want. What is going wrong in my functions?

Comment: You don't have a check to see when to replace the character. So add `if` `else` to your first function

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
def replace(word,char1,char2):
    newString = ""
    for next_char in word:         # for each character in the word
        if next_char == char1:     # if it is the character you want to replace
            newString += char2     # add the new character to the new string
        else:                      # otherwise
            newString += next_char # add the original character to the new string
    return newString
```

Although strings in python already have a method that does this:

```
print "cake".replace("a", "o")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def replace(word, ch1, ch2) :
    return ''.join([ch2 if i == ch1 else i for i in word])
```